# In build notification bar in android

Tags: android

Any one can tell me how could i get inbuild notification listner in android. What all i want is if user put password on screen and if then some notification arrives. and if user click on notification, I want password field should be reset.

Comment: What you try so far..

Comment: Show us your code for getting correct solution for your problem.

Comment: I dont have code as of now.. but how can i get android's in built notification touch event listner.. Thnx in advance!!

Comment: @Udg did you tried the approach I had described in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just clear the password field in the `onPause` method of the activity? If the user clicks on the notification, the pending intent will launch a new activity (most in the cases from another application). When your activity is no longer the foreground activity, its `onPause` method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateNotification to create a local notification.
In the intent you use for the notification add an extra bit of data that you define (e.g. "ClearPassword" as a boolean of true).
In your activity, check for extras and your specific extra and if it is set then you can clear the field.